# DIV with 100% height is cutting off scrollbar

Tags: css, html, height

I've looked on this forum for divs with 100% height problems and can't seem to find the exact problem I'm having. Basically I have a div with 100% height and part of the scrollbar is cut off. How do I fix this? I've enclosed sample code below.

**HTML:**

```
<body style="height:150px;">
        <div style="height:150px;padding:0px;margin:0px;border:0px" >
          <DIV class="wrapper">
            <TABLE id="title_table" >
              <TR class="titleHeader_row" oncontextmenu="return false;">
                <TH class="coltitleExpand_cell">123
                </TH>
                <TH class="coltitle_cell">123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH class="coltitle_cell">123<br/>123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH class="coltitle_cell">123<br/>123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH class="coltitle_cell">123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH class="coltitle_cell">123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH class="coltitle_cell">123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH class="coltitle_cell">123<br/>123
                </TH>
                        <TH class="coltitle_cell">123<br/>123
                </TH>
                </TR>
                </TABLE>
          <DIV  class="record_div"  id="coldata_div">
            <TABLE class="record_table" id="coldata_table">
              <TR>
                <TD class="dummy_cell"></TD>
                <TH >123
                </TH>
                <TH >123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH >123<br/>123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH >123<br/>123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH >123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH >123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH >123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH >123<br/>123
                </TH>
                </TR>
                      <TR>
                <TD class="dummy_cell"></TD>
                <TH >123
                </TH>
                <TH >123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH >123<br/>123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH >123<br/>123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH >123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH >123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH >123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH >123<br/>123
                </TH>
                </TR>
                              <TR>
                <TD class="dummy_cell"></TD>
                <TH >123
                </TH>
                <TH >123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH >123<br/>123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH >123<br/>123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH >123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH >123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH >123<br/>123
                </TH>
                <TH >123<br/>123
                </TH>
                </TR>
                </TABLE>
        </div>
        </DIV>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0px 0px 0px 3px;
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.dummy_cell {
  width: 45px;
}

.wrapper table {
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.wrapper #title_table {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper th {
  font: normal;
}

.wrapper #title_table .titleHeader_row {
  background-color: #E7F0F7;
  font: 11px bold Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper #title_table .titleHeader_row th.coltitle_cell {
  border: 1px solid #a7cbe3;
  border-left: none;
  font: bold 11px;
  min-height: 35px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper #title_table .titleHeader_row .coltitleExpand_cell {
  border: 1px solid #a7cbe3;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  width: 45px;
}

.wrapper #title_table {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper th {
  font: normal;
}

.wrapper #title_table .titleHeader_row {
  background-color: #E7F0F7;
  font: 11px bold Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper #title_table .titleHeader_row th.coltitle_cell {
  border: 1px solid #a7cbe3;
  border-left: none;
  font: bold 11px;
  min-height: 35px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .results_row {
  display: inline;
}

.record_div {
  margin:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}

.wrapper .record_div .record_table {
  table-layout:fixed;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `overflow:hidden` from the `.wrapper` selector

See this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WAh72/) for working example.

Comment: Alright. That worked for this example. However, my problem is a little more complicated. The provided code is actually an html file within an iframe. 

<iframe src="TableScroll.html" scrolling="no" style="height:150px">

I'm trying to shrink record_div to fit the scrollbar within the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're missing a  tag near the end.

Edit: Wow just saw the age of this question... haha